# question about inversion

Tags: inversion

I have read something in the site that inversion means if `i<j` then `A[i]>A[j]` and it has some exercises about this , I have a lot of questions but I want to ask just one of them at first and then i will do the other exercises by myself if I can!!

Exercise: **What permutation array (1,2, ..., n) has the highest number of inversion? What are these?**
thanks

Comment: Based on your previous questions, I am tagging this as homework. Feel free to remove it, if it is not. If it is homework, I suggest you leave it, as people will be more helpful (to your understanding of the subject matter) if you have any doubts etc.

Comment: it is not my home work but  I need people to be more helpful so I save this tag :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly `N, ..., 2, 1` has the highest number of inversions. Every pair is an inversion. For example for `N = 6`, we have `6 5 4 3 2 1`. The inversions are `6-5, 6-4, 6-3, 6-2, 6-1, 5-4, 5-3` and so on. Their number is `N * (N - 1) / 2`.

Comment: aha I get it also thanks for your link mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationInversion.html

Comment: also is this correct that if the array is more in order its inversion will be more???

Comment: More in order is not a defined term. But intuitively a permutation which is more reversed will probably have more inversions than a non-reversed. But again it depends on the permutations you compare.

Answer (score 0):

Well,  the identity permutation (1,2,...,n) has no inversions. Since an inversion is a pair of elements that are in reverse order than their indices, the answer probably involves some reversal of that permutation.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard the term *inversion* used in this way.

A decreasing array of length N, for N>0, has 1/2*N*(N-1) pairs i<j with A[i]>A[j].  This is the maximum possible.

Comment: @Petar: Thanks.  I think Knuth doesn't use the term.